# can't edit plist as xml in textedit, give binary representation when opened

Tags: xcode, plist, textedit

This worked before now it's not working. I opened `plist` in `TextEdit` and shows a binary format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because apple has changed the format now. I don't know exactly when but you can change it.

Open `Terminal` and use below commands

```
plutil -convert xml1 my.plist
```

Edit your `my.plist` in `TextEdit` and save it. Then convert `my.plist` file to binary as below

```
plutil -convert binary1 my.plist
```

Where `xml1` and `binary1` are the format, read more about [**`plutil`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/plutil.1.html)